# When an element is clicked, go up the parentNode until a specific parent is found

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, event-bubbling

I would like to set a click event listener in vanilla javascript on an UL , then on a click inside of that, I want to get the element clicked, check to see if it is an LI, if it is not - go up the parentNode until LI is reached, if it is - get it, if its not - stop at the UL.

Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/urbbsu0t/4/

I tried many methods and read a few articles, but everything I find works when there are no nested elements, ie if I have a single element inside the LI. But how can I compare them if I have many children?

Here is an example of an LI element

```
<li class="service">
  <div class="service-body">

    <h1>Title goes here</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt dicta 
    laborum, excepturi tenetur vero cum!</p>

    <button>button goes here</button>
  </div>
</li>
```

```js
const services = document.querySelector('.services');

services.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 
})
```

```css
.services {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.service {flex 1 30%; max-width: 30%;}
```

```html
<ul class="services">
  <li class="service">
    <div class="service-body">
      <h1>Title goes here</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus sequi ab quod.</p>
      <button>button goes here</button>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="service">
    <div class="service-body">
      <h1>Title goes here</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, officiis?</p>
      <button>button goes here</button>
     </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="service">
    <div class="service-body">
      <h1>Title goes here</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt dicta laborum, excepturi tenetur vero cum!</p>
      <button>button goes here</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):

> The Element.closest() method returns the closest ancestor of the
>   current element (or the current element itself) which matches the
>   selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it
>   returns null.

**Example:**

```js
const services = document.querySelector('.services');

services.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const li = e.target.closest('.service');
  
  if(li) li.style.color = 'red';
});
```

```css
.services {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.service {flex 1 30%; max-width: 30%;}
```

```html
<ul class="services">
  <li class="service">
    <div class="service-body">
      <h1>Title goes here</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus sequi ab quod.</p>
      <button>button goes here</button>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="service">
    <div class="service-body">
      <h1>Title goes here</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, officiis?</p>
      <button>button goes here</button>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="service">
    <div class="service-body">
      <h1>Title goes here</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt dicta laborum, excepturi tenetur vero cum!</p>
      <button>button goes here</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Spot on, just, while the chances are slim, in case OP does need to support IE, this does not work in IE.

Comment: Is there a way to add support for IE, at least for the later versions? This works exactly as I want

Comment: closest doesn't work on Safari for example, use a polyfill